# Where did the haskell list difference operator (\\) go?

Tags: list, haskell, haskell-prelude

Am I missing something? It seems I don't have the [list difference operator](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:-92--92-) defined...

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.6.5: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> "Hello World!" \\ "ell W"

<interactive>:1:16: error:
    Variable not in scope: (\\) :: [Char] -> [Char] -> t
Prelude> :t (\\)

<interactive>:1:1: error: Variable not in scope: \\
Prelude> :type (\\)

<interactive>:1:1: error: Variable not in scope: \\
Prelude> :type (++)
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

Did it get removed? (And if so, where do I look to see that?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in `Data.List`:

```
% ghci
GHCi, version 8.4.4: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :t (\\)

<interactive>:1:1: error: Variable not in scope: \\
Prelude> import Data.List
Prelude Data.List> :t (\\)
(\\) :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

Comment: I see you're running an even older version of GHC than @scnlf. Is there some reason you're not up to 8.10 -- or 9.x?